# Adding NFS shares to FSTAB

Tags: system, networking, release-hera

Ive moved from Ubuntu to ElementaryOS and the only drawback I've had is with my NFS shares. I usually setup my NFS shares via FSTAB however I receive an error after trying to open the share. However in Ubuntu I dont get this error and my shares work perfectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: NFS Error]

Here is my FSTAB also

[image: FSTAB]

Comment: interesting ... after the error ... are any of the NFS mounts there? ... ie show output of df -h after the attempted mount ... also a thought ... you might want to put "noauto" on the NFS mounts and manually mount them with a script ... bash script would not be difficult to write ... my thought on this it could be a timing issue on when thw NFS mount is being attempted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `user` to the fstab nfs mount options. For example:

```
192.168.1.11:/volume1/applications /home/rob/Darth/Applications nfs user,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad Pop, this worked!!!